# Entity Framework 4.0 trouble matching conceptual model with CLR types?

Tags: entity-framework-4, ado.net

I'm getting a weird error in my application I cant solve. The error is the following.

```
The Member 'Company' in the conceptual model type 'EntityModel.FK_Users_Companies' is not present in the CLR type 'EntityModel.FK_Users_Companies'.
```

This is very strange to me and I cant find anything about this exact error when I google it.

Any suggestions on how to solve it?

Comment: Did you make any refactoring in your code? Did you change a name of any property without changing it in EDMX file?

Comment: Yes, I moved some classes in to another assembly/project. But did not make any changes for a property name or in the database. 
I have also removed the .EDMX and create a new one with the same error.

Comment: You must exactly describe what you did in your question otherwise you cannot expect to get any useful answers. We don't see your projects.

Comment: I moved a lot around, removed 2 projects and merged 2 others. Moved my MetadataType/partial classes to a new project. Changed alot. So its very hard to describe exactly what I have changed. My question is what this error means, where do it fail?

Comment: Then we cannot help you. The solution for you is obvious - move Entities back to one project.

Comment: Yes I know its hard to help without the complete picture, but what does this Error message means? What´s the difference between the _conceptual model type_ and _CLR Type_?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this error is now solved.

In my solution I had a project **Data** where my EMDX file where stored and an ASP.NET MVC 3 project, and some other projects as well. Anyhow. The solutions for this problem was to copy the ConnectionString in App.Config in the Data project and put it in the Web.Config in the ASP.NET MVC 3 project.

I hade already done this but somehow there had slipped in a mismatch between the two connection strings.

Answer (score 1):

The error means that your class (CLR type) is not in sync with your EDMX model (conceptual model type). The most obvious reason is that your class has refactored name of navigation property but your EDMX doesn't have.

Comment: Thanks, is there any easy way to re-sync the class and EDMX model? Not even when I remove the EDMX file and recreate it the error disappears.

Comment: When you recreate EDMX do you also recreate all your entity classes (= delete old one and let EF create them again)?

Comment: I delete model.emdx file and I guess the model.Designer.cs is also deleted at the same time. Is there any other files needed to be removed?

Comment: No there should not be any other files needed to delete. Are you sure that there are no other classes named `Company` in your application?